# Is there a limit to the number of Media objects I should use in an Android Phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a limit to the number of Media objects I should use in an Android Phonegap app?  Reason being is my app has about 30 wav files and after playing about 5 or 6 it tends to crash.  Is there anything to improve this?  I tried the .release() method but didn't seem to help...

Answer (score 0):

Android has a "finite amount of OpenCore instances for media playback".

You say that .release() isn't helping... when are you calling it?

Have you seen Simon Mac Donald's post on the Media API?

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html

As a last resort, check to see if the following issue is effecting you:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/issues/208

cheers,